# First leg delayed, skipped delayed last leg - Can I claim compensation?

Tags: air-travel, compensation, lot-polish-airlines

I was recently flying from Tokyo Narita (NRT) to Prague (PRG) with a connection in Warsaw (WAW), with LOT Polish Airlines (single booking).
The NRT->WAW flight was delayed by 6h30m. Hence we missed the WAW->PRG flight and were offered the flight following morning.
However, we did not take it and decided to stay in Warsaw as flying to Prague the next day would be pointless in our case.

Can we count on compensation in this case? If yes, to what extent? Does the fact we did not take the next-day WAW->PRG flight change anything in terms of possible compensation?

Comment: What did the airline say about compensation rights when you told them you weren’t going to take up the offer of the next day flight?

Comment: I had been in similar situation. No response from LOT yet. See this : https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140102/flight-compensation-with-agent

Comment: @Traveller They only said I can contact them and get a refund for the WAW->PRG flight.

Comment: @Dexter I think your situation is quite different as you did fly the second leg.

Comment: @tomi.lee.jones, yes you are right. I missed that part.

Comment: I think you have to go more into details about the circumstances around this situation to perhaps get any good answer. Why was it pointless to continue to Prague the next day? Why was it acceptable to stay in Warsaw when your original intention was to be in Prague? Your case may be covered by article 8(1)(a) of the EU air passenger compensation regulation, but that requires a more or less subjective evaluation of your situation to decide how much compensation you are entitled to and LOT will not likely subjectively evaluate in your favour.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo So what you're saying is that the fact we didn't get on the connecting flight *does* indeed matter if it's necessary for me to explain the reason behind our choice? From what I understand if we got on the flight we would be delayed by almost 24h and had every right to claim compensation. But anyway: We were planning to stay in Prague and made arrangements for 2 days and then head home (not by plane). The delay forced us to cancel the arrangements and there was not point in flying to Prague just to stay there for half a day. But again, why would that matter?

Comment: *If* you had decided to continue the journey, LOT would have had to arrange accomodation for you in Warsaw for the night you would have been forced to stay there and you would have been entitled to monetary compensation for the delay. It gets much more complicated when you decided to interrupt the journey. If the anticipated delay is more than 5 hours, you have the right to do so, but as I understand it, your default compensation is then restricted to a refund of the part of the ticket not used. Potential further compensation depends on the exact circumstances.

Comment: Please don't just use airport codes. They're dangerous because they mean that typoes can completely destroy the meaning of your question (e.g., one missed keypress turns PRG into PTG in South Africa) and they mean that people who don't know the codes have to look them up to figure out what your situation is. That makes your question much less useful to people in the future who might be in a similar situation.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo So the ruling is quite clear in the case (Article 8, right to reimbursement): "full cost of the ticket (...) for the part or parts of the journey not made, *and for the part or parts already made* if the flight is no longer serving any purpose" - What makes you think the "default" is only for the part not made? How would airline objectively calculate the amount to refund if the flight is part of a single itinerary?

Comment: The regulation is not clear at all, but open to interpretation. You are only entitled to refund of the parts of ticket already used if *objectively* the flight is no longer serving any purpose. That is why I now for the third time is trying to tell that you have to reveal the exact circumstances for someone to be able to answer your question. Your personal assesment, that the flight is not serving any purpose, is in this case irrelevant. Refund of parts of a multi-leg ticket is usually based on the distance of each segment.